# How add new row in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8U7T.png)

I got a jqgrid, and I am trying to add a row by click the "+" botton, which is marked red. But the template is blank.

Below is scripts in JavaScripts.

```
$("#table_list_1").jqGrid({
    url: "usermanage/getMainTableJson",
    datatype:"json",
    mytype:"GET",
    height: 250,
    autowidth:true,
    colNames:['id','username','realname','email','createtime','updatetime'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:'10%',align:'center'},
        {name:'username',index:'username', width:'15%',align:'center'},
        {name:'realname',index:'realname', width:'20%', align:"center"},
        {name:'email',index:'email', width:'25%', align:"center"},
        {name:'createdate',index:'createdate', width:'15%', align:"center", sortable:false},
        {name:'updatedate',index:'updatedate', width:'15%',align:"center", sortable:false}
    ],
    rownumbers:false,
    sortname:'id',
    sortorder:'asc',
    viewrecords:true,
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,40],
    pager:$('#pager_list_1'),
    add:true,
    edit:true,
    addtext:'Add',
    edittext:'Edit'

});

$("#table_list_1").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager_list_1',
    {edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true},
    {height: 200, reloadAfterSubmit: true}
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `editable: true` property to the column, which you want to allow to edit. You can use `cmTemplate` property to specify *default* values for any property. Thus you can use for example the option

```
cmTemplate: { editable: true }
```

and to add `editable: false` to the column `id`. As the result all properties with exception `id` will be seen in the Add/Edit dialog.

Comment: After add { editable: true } for item,  it works! Thanks Oleg!

Comment: I am a new member in stackoverflow. Thanks very much for your reminder. I accepted your Answer. Thanks~